# MongoDB replica set configuration through js file

Tags: mongodb

I have configured a replica set for MongoDB manually.

Once I have launched the daemons on 3 nodes and after they are up and running, from the node which I have identified as "Primary" I run the following command:

1. `mongo`

   - This will drop me into the mongo shell
2. `use admin`
3. Create replica set config:

   ```
   cfg = {
       _id: 'csReplicaSet',
       members: [
           { _id: 0, host: 'node1IpAddress:27017'},
           { _id: 1, host: 'node2IpAddress:27017'},
           { _id: 2, host: 'node3IpAddress:27017', arbiterOnly: true}
       ]
   }
   ```
4. `rs.initiate(cfg)`

I want to know how can I do these steps in a JavaScript file that will be recognised by mongo. I want to automate these steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Passing your init script to the `mongo` shell

Programmatically, you're almost there. You could save your instructions to a JavaScript file and run this on the `mongo` command line. You should also capture & print the results of `rs.initiate()` in case there is an error:

eg. contents of `initreplica.js`:

```
var cfg = { _id: 'csReplicaSet',
    members: [
        { _id: 0, host: 'node1IpAddress:27017'},
        { _id: 1, host: 'node2IpAddress:27017'},
        { _id: 2, host: 'node3IpAddress:27017', arbiterOnly: true}
    ]
};

var error = rs.initiate(cfg);
printjson(error);
```

Run this from the command line with:

```
 mongo node1IpAddress:27017/admin initreplica.js
```

Note that this assumes your three `mongod` nodes have been started on the same IP addresses including `--replSet csReplicaSet` parameter. You also only need to do this init sequence once unless you are rebuilding the replica set from scratch (and there is no existing replica set config).

I would also recommend reading the section of the manual on [Writing Scripts for the `mongo` shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/). It includes some helpful hints such as how to open new connections to other MongoDB servers as well as the [JavaScript equivalents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo) of some shell helpers like `use <db>`.

#### Automating a production deployment

If you're looking for ways to automate building a production MongoDB cluster, you should look into recipes for configuration management tools like Chef or Puppet. There is also an [Automation feature](https://mms.mongodb.com/learn-more/automation) coming soon as part of MMS (MongoDB Management Service); the Automation feature is currently in beta testing.

Comment: On reboot, how can I restore this replica configuration and start automcatically everthing ? What extra care I should take for this to happen ?

Comment: The replica set configuration is saved in the `local` database, so after a reboot you just need to ensure all the `mongod` services are started. In order to have a primary elected, you need to have a strict majority of your replica set available (so in your 3 node case, that means at least 2/3 nodes running).

Answer (score 1):

I Just run it this way

```
mongo --port 27018 init_replica.set.js
```

and this is the script for init from the

```
config = { _id: "m101", members:[
          { _id : 0, host : "MYHOST:27017" ,priority : 0, slaveDelay : 5 },
          { _id : 1, host : "MYHOST:27018"},
          { _id : 2, host : "MYHOST:27019"} ]
};
rs.initiate(config);
rs.status();
```